# RGB mat to avi matlab

Tags: matlab, video, rgb, mat

I have 300 frames of RGB mat data and I was wondering if there was a way to use videowriter to convert those mat frames into an avi file? I have tried using imwrite and videowriter but I cannot get the code to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your data is formatted, but here is a small program to help you get started:

```
% Generate sample frames
for i = 1:300
    frames{i} = rand(240, 300, 3);
end

% Write sample frames to disk
v = VideoWriter('c:/data/test.avi');
v.open;
for i = 1:300
    v.writeVideo(frames{i});
end
v.close;
```

There are a lot of parameters in your AVI that you can tweak, including the file format and frame rate. Refer to the [VideoWriter documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html).

If by *mat data* you mean separate mat files containing a single variable with the frame information, you need to load each mat file inside your loop and write the data to the VideoWriter object. For example, assuming that all the mat files are under `c:/data/frames` folder and the names are in the `frame1.mat` to `frame300.mat` format, and each mat file has a single variable called `frame`:

```
for i = 1:300
    load (sprintf('c:/data/frames/frame%d.mat', i), 'frame');
    v.writeVideo(frame);
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I was over complicating things and trying to use imwrite.